# Type of enum can't be created from string

Tags: c#, enums

My function gets enum types as strings which I need to validate.

Why do the parsedType(s) are null here?

```
var parsedType1 = Type.GetType("System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left");
var parsedType2 = Type.GetType("System.Windows.TextAlignment");
```

though this works?

```
var parsedType3 = Type.GetType("System.String");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line would fail because `System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left` isn't the name of a *type* - it's the name of a *field* within a type.

The second line would fail because when you provide `Type.GetType(string)` with just a type name, without any assembly part, it looks in the currently executing assembly and `mscorlib`. That's why `"System.String"` works.

If you know which assembly the type will be in, just use `Assembly.GetType(string)` instead.

For example:

```
// Here TextDataFormat is just another type that's in the same assembly
Type textAlignment = typeof(TextDataFormat).Assembly.GetType("System.Windows.TextAlignment");
```

Or you could specify the assembly name in the string:

```
Type textAlignment = Type.GetType("System.Windows.TextAlignment, PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35");
```